# WMP object not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, windows-media-player

I am facing an issue with `WMP` object video playing in `IE11`.

Same video is playing well in `IE10`.

System configuration is as below:

> OS: Windows 7 ultimate SP1
>   IE : 11.0.9600.18204
>   WMP version: 12.0.7601.18840
>   IE Document mode : 10 (Default)
>   User agent string : Default

I also tried to change document mode and `user-agent` string, but no luck.

I have searched a lot but not found any solution.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of "IE11 prevents ActiveX from running"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151999/ie11-prevents-activex-from-running)

Comment: But its working well in IE11 other versions. Let me give you version: 
11.0.9600.18097 - working - Windows 7
11.0.9600.18204 - not working - Windows 7
11.0.9600.16384 - not working - Windows 8

Comment: Are you sure that it's not every version compiled after [they started to block ActiveX](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/08/06/activex-blocking-in-internet-explorer.aspx)?

Comment: Yes these all versions are latest compiled after