# I can't load any active x component on IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, internet-explorer-11

Ever since I formatted my computer, I am not able to load any active x component for any site. I get the following error:

> ActiveX is not supported

For example, I opened the following page in IE11:
https://www.pcpitstop.com/testax.asp

It should display the date, but it doesn't, it just gives the active x not supported error. I changed in IE security settings but that didn't fix it.

[image: Active X not supported error.]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS/software tech support. And most people would consider the inability to load ActiveX to be a **GOOD** thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 prevents ActiveX from running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151999/ie11-prevents-activex-from-running)

Answer (score 0):

IE displays a active x warning and ask for permission if you allow it to run or not. To overcome this the only solution is to;
Open Internet Explorer. 
Click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Options.
On the Security tab, click the Custom level button. 
Scroll down the Security Settings list until you see ActiveX controls and plug-ins. 
For Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls, click Enable.
Scroll down to Download signed ActiveX controls and click Enable or Prompt.
Scroll down to Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins and click Enable or Prompt.
Scroll down to Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting and click Enable or Prompt.
Click OK, and then click OK again.