# Automation server can't create object on IE11

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run .exe file in javascript

**Code:**

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
objShell.run('C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WAcoount.exe', 1, false);
```

an error is :

> Automation server can't create object

For this i changed setting IE 11

Tools -> Internet Options -> choose the Security tab
Click the Custom Level button
Enable the following settings:
Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins
Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe.(Enable)

But still an issue is there.

Comment: (1) Try regular backslashes, (2) Are you sure that **`WAcoount`** is spelled correctly?

Comment: spelling is right.

Comment: yeah i change to  objShell.run('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\WAcoount.exe', 1, false); still same issue

Comment: Maybe this helps, especially what is mentioned in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631205/1220550