# How to use dll in angular5 project

Tags: javascript, angular, dll, internet-explorer-11

I have to use a dll created in c# and use in angular5 project. How can I use this dll without registering? the problem is related to IE11 only.

I have successfully created the dll and placed that dll in one of the folders in D drive. Now, I want to use a method in dll. For that, I want to use this dll to help me in calling a particular method.

I have used ActiveX control for using dll.
I did:

```
let obj = new ActiveXObject('DynamicWrapperX');
```

this line is giving error 'ERROR Error: Automation server can't create object'.

but if, I am using:

```
let fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
```

I am not getting any error.

I want to use my dll, which is present in another folder. But, I don't want to register the dll.

I want to use dll stored in any other folder in angular5 app, preferably without registering and call a method in the dll.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this qustion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151999/ie11-prevents-activex-from-running

Comment: No, That question tells IE prevents Activex. Here I am asking for how to use dll. I am using ActiveX and till now everything is working with filesystemobject

Comment: You could try to integrate the .dll file with rest service or node.js, then using angular to call the related methods. Also, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791334/call-function-from-dll-loaded-in-front-end-javascript-load-dll-in-clientside-ja) to use EdgeJS.